# Got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

```
"abc:def"
```

I need to check if it matches. If yes, I want to apply a regex and retrieve first part of it (`"abc"`).

Here is my try:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*:.*");
String  name = "abc:def"
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(group);
}
```

It gives me

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1

Comment: well you are checking for `.*:.*` which will result in only one group, since it is only found once. Try using `group(0)` and you will notice it.

Comment: Read doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) inside your regular expression. This is done by putting what you want to capture inside parentheses:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*):.*"); // <-- parentheses here
String  name = "abc:def";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(group); // prints "abc"
}
```

Comment: Does not answer OP's question though.

Comment: @Neijwiert actually OP didn´t provide a question, just a task and an exception.

Comment: @KevinEsche Ok, true, but it looks like he's trying to resolve his exception. I'm not trying to say I disagree with this answer.

Comment: @Neijwiert I don't understand. This will resolve the exception.

Answer (score 4):

You only have a `group (0)` (full match) because you don't define any **capturing groups** (enclosed in `(` and `)`) in your regex.

If you change your code to include a capturing group like this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^:]*):.*"); 
String  name = "abc:def";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String fullMatch = matcher.group(0);
    String group = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(group);
}
```

you'll have full match "abc:def" and first group (until first colon) "abc"

Answer (score 0):

There is no capturing group in your `Pattern`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*:.*");
```

See the [documentation of Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details.

I assume you need this instead:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*):.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;



    public class HelloWorld
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          String patternString = ".*:.*";

         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
         String  name = "abc:def";
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

         while(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(0));
            }

      }
    }
```